# Dependencies issues when installing MUI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, dependencies

[enter image description here][1]

I tried installing mui styles and other components to my local computer, but am unable do do so. It shows some dependency error. How do I fix it?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqxtS.png

```
npm install @mui/styles
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: archit_website@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.9.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/styles
npm ERR!   @mui/styles@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/home/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/home/.npm/_logs/2022-07-15T16_59_52_863Z-debug-0.log
```

I also tried using npm install @mui/styles --force
but it still doesn't solve it

Answer (score 2):

`@mui/styles` is not compatible with React v18. You can find legacy API here: https://mui.com/system/styles/api/

> @mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18.

Two solutions:

You can either use an alternative styling solution. Or, you can use/install `@mui/system` instead.

Please refer to this doc by MUI:
https://mui.com/system/basics/